# Difference between UrlDecode() and QueryString()

Tags: c#, encryption

When I decrypt this string as a hard coded parameter I get the five digit number I expect.

string result =  Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode("ha3bEv8A%2ffs0goPGeO6NPQ%3d%3d"));

However when I try to grab it from the URL...

http://localhost:12345/pagename?id=ha3bEv8A%2ffs0goPGeO6NPQ%3d%3d

string result1 = Decrypt(Request.QueryString["id"]);

The Decrypt method produces a "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" error. I made sure the PaddingMode matches which seems to be the cause of this sort of thing most of the time.

Also, I've noticed the only difference between what UrlDecode() and QueryString() produce is certain letters are in caps in the former.

ha3bEv8A/fs0goPGeO6NPQ==

ha3bev8a/fs0gopgeo6npq==

Is there a setting that would make it produce the same string? Because one decrypts properly and the other errors out.

I've included the Encrypt and Decrypt methods I'm using...

```
   private string Encrypt(string clearText)
     {
        string EncryptionKey = "hyddhrii%2moi43Hd5%%";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
        byte[] salt = 
       new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d,0x65, 0x64, 0x76,   
        0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 };


        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = 
           new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, salt);
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return clearText;
    }



  public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "hyddhrii%2moi43Hd5%%";
        cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        byte[] salt = new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 
        0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 };
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey,  
            salt);
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

Comment: Base64 encoding is case sensitive so if you decode the string with incorrect casing the data will be completely different, this can break padding schemes by corrupting the padding chars.  If you have a string with incorrect casing you cannot convert it back to a correctly cased version & the data is irretrievable.

Comment: ASP.Net's Request.QueryString() should certainly not change the case of the value, are you certain thats whats happening?

Comment: Why would the casing be incorrect? If I encrypt the original number, I get the string that I'm using.  Why wouldn't I be able to reverse that?